# Java Robot class keyPress not typing into google chrome

Tags: java, keypress, awtrobot

I'm trying to beat the game 'fastTyper 2' (basically just a typing game where you type words that appear as fast as possible) by using the java robot class to type in the letters for me. I've successfully taken in the letters to be typed. However, it seems that the robot's keyPress method isn't working due to some kind of protection the game has. Does anyone know of a way to get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the game protection is stopping you because there is no way for a game(or any other program) to decide whether the key is pressed manually or programatically. 
Maybe you need to check the logic at what point of time you need your Robot class to press the key and which key to press(and make sure that you pass correct parameter value to keyPress method)